# coldfusion <cfdirectory> windows domain controller network drive permission

Tags: coldfusion, permissions, dns, controller, cfdirectory

I have an issue accessing a directory using `<cfdirectory>` in ColdFusion. I'm a bit new in ColdFusion, if I issue:

```
<cfset mPath = "\\192.168.0.18\share\Pol\">
<cfdirectory directory="#mPath#" action="list" name="dir" sort="#url.sort#">
```

This code can list the directory and all of it's folders.

But when I chose a password protected drive over the network it can't display anything. The results are empty, but I actually have folders inside in this drive.

We are running under Windows Domain Controller. My account is allowed full access control and also the ColdFusionserver IP or account as well.

```
<cfset mPath = "\\192.168.0.21\hse_scan">
<cfdirectory directory="#mPath#" action="list" name="dir" sort="#url.sort#">
```

No folders and subfolders detected in ColdFusion.

Is there anything I could set in the ColdFusion Server settings?

Answer (score 0):

You said *your* account has full access, but ColdFusion - by default - will not be starting up using your account, it'll be using the local system account (check this in the Services control panel). TO access network resources, ColdFusion will also need to run using a domain account. I suspect this is your problem.